# How to re-enable a disabled google groups member

Tags: google-groups

I have a google group with a bunch of users-- everything is great until today one of my users tells me she was trying to post something and got a bounce back from the google group.  In the bounce-back, it says "Technical details of permanent failure: The account xxxx is disabled."

When I look at the user in the list of members (using the new google group interface), it says "Disabled" (in red letters) for her in the "Delivery" column.  When I click on her entry, everything looks normal except that the first "Posting permission" option is "Default group policy: member is **not** allowed to post" (emphasis mine).  This is doubly odd since 1) the default group policy is that all members are allowed to post and 2) she was last able to post something to the group about 2 weeks ago without incident (and without any changes to her subscription by the list owner-- me).

I've tried setting the user's "Posting permission" to "Override: member is allowed to post" to no avail; she still gets the "account ... is disabled" bounceback.

I've tried deleting the user from the group and then putting her back on using a "direct add".  She still shows as "disabled" and gets the same bounceback.

I checked to make sure she's not on the "banned" list; she's not.  Just for kicks, I tried banning her and then unbanning her, then direct adding her again.  She still shows as "disabled".

The only reference I can find around the web about an account being disabled mentions that this can happen if the user sends 500+ messages in a 24-hour period.  This user assures me she's done no such thing.

How can I re-enable this group member's subscription?

Update: I deleted the user from the list and she then used the google groups website to re-subscribe.  In doing so, she said that the site told her that there had been suspicious activity on her account and required her to provide some sort of credentials.  The subscription request came in for approval and the user is now showing as being a regular (albeit new) subscriber.

Comment: You should put the update information into an answer if it worked.

Comment: So is this issue resolved?

Comment: @Hydra I'm not sure-- I was hoping someone had experienced this and would be like "oh, I twiddled this setting and voila, it as fixed" without having to get the user involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that here, "disabled" is referring to a global *(google-wide)* status across the whole Google account -- that the suspicious activity was detected and Google was just waiting for the account to be re-activated before they start accepting mail from it again (consider the case of someone else using it to send spam - you want to block the account until the problem is fixed).

Comment: I think you're probably right.  I'll "accept" your answer since it's the best (only?) one offered to resolve the issue (from the standpoint of "there's nothing else to be done").

Comment: I have the same problem with one of my users - but they are using an active account, and I've not even added them to the group ever (and I can't). Here is my similar post: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120480/valid-user-blocked-from-google-groups