# Valid user blocked from Google Groups

Tags: gmail, google-groups

We have a Google Apps platform, and I have created a google group there, but there is a particular user with a regular, working Gmail account whom I cannot add to the group.

> Some email addresses cannot be added to this group because their accounts are disabled or are blocked from Google Groups

The account is their primary email account which they use all the time.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can they join any other Google Groups? [chromium-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev) is a good one to try (linked from [here](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys), select to receive no mail)

Comment: I don't think she uses groups at all; I think maybe she unchecked the setting for "Allow group administrators to send you invites" in her google groups settings - I'm checking on that.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't.  The user was in the midst of moving to another city and has not had time to deal with me over this.  I suspect that maybe she has some setting marked in her google account.  I'm waiting to take a peek though - haven't given up on it yet.